# emacs, erlang and file association

Tags: windows, emacs, erlang

I associated the .erl extension to runemacs.exe
When I double-click on a erl file, emacs doesn't open it.
If I open a erl file from the file menu of emacs, emacs opens the file !

- a buffer is called as the erl file, the buffer is empty;
- a buffer is called Program c:/, the buffer is empty

.emacs file is in C:/

What is my error, what is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I have a guess of what might be the problem. Do you have spaces in the file path? If so, runemacs.exe might treat the path as two different files and open them.

Secondly, I would recommend using "emacs server". By issuing `M-x server-start RET` in Emacs, and associate .erl with "emacsclient", you could open files in a running Emacs rather than starting a new one.

Comment: Thank you but with server-start I have the "unsafe" message already invoked in its forum and the solutions don't fix the problem for me. For the environment PATH variable, yes I have spaces. Within .emacs file, I suppressed the spaces. I will try to change PATH.

Comment: I changed the path to emacs in PATH environment variable: no change !